# "is each" or "are each"?

Tags: verb-agreement, agreement

I haven't found an answer on any of the boards related to 'each' that seems to answer this specific question:

I have included the following in draft correspondence:

> Organization x and organization y are each responsible for nominating one member to the board.

My boss has amended this to:

> Organization x and organization y is each responsible for nominating one member to the board.

I understand he has done this because 'each' takes a singular verb; however in this case I think he is wrong, because the subject is 'organization x and organization y'.

Nevertheless, I am thinking of rewording to:

> Organization x and organization y are responsible for nominating one member to the board each.

or

> Organization x and organization y must each nominate one member to the board.

Of these, I think the last is clearest, the only problem is that it slightly more emphatic than I wish to be.

I would appreciate any views on the best construction.

Comment: *Organization X, Organization Y, and Organization Z are each* but *Each of Organization X, Organization Y, and Organization Z is*.

Comment: Thanks - I am trying to decide whether to stick to my guns or re-formulate the sentence...

Answer (score 2):

As Choster says in a comment:

> *Organization X, Organization Y, and Organization Z are each* but *Each of Organization X, Organization Y, and Organization Z is*

According to the [Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/each?q=each),

> When **each** is used after a plural subject, it has a plural verb: *They
>   each have their own email address.*

And as you note, the subject of the sentence is in this case the plural noun phrase "Organization x and organization y."
So the original sentence is grammatically correct, but the reworded versions are also fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would see it as "Organization x and organization y are, each of them,  responsible for nominating one member to the board."

Answer (score -1):

Substitute "They" and it becomes obvious that your take is the correct one

Comment: But why? This doesn't even begin to answer the question.